# Webpage never end loading when i update the security stamp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

As the title says whenever i update the security stamp with the method below, any session aside from the current one (the one that changes the password works just fine), cannot ever enter the webpage again unless they delete manually the cookies, my aim was to be able to revoke all cookie sessions to the identity server, so i added the SecurityStampValidatorOptions . Is not a problem specifically of the [Authorize] attribute i think, because it get stuck even loading the .well-known/configuration endpoint. Im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePass(ChangePassViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);

        var changePassword = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, model.ViejaPass, model.NuevaPass);

        if (!changePassword.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in changePassword.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.TryAddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.RedirectUrl))
            return Redirect("http://localhost:3000"); // aca tenemos que definir a donde lo mandamos
        else
            return Redirect(model.RedirectUrl);

    }
```

This is my services pipeline

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString(_config, "Conn");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
        //var certificate = CertHelper.GetCertificate(); TODO: look how to import cert to docker

        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        services.AddDbContext<IdenServerDbContext>(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServer(
                conn,
                o => o.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)
            );
        });

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdenServerDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "IdentityServer.Cookie";
            config.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
            config.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        });

        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        });

        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(conn,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(conn,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddTransient<CustomUserManager>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmpresaService, EmpresaService>();
        services.AddScoped<IImagenService, ImagenService>();


        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });
    }
```

this is my configuration pipeline

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, CustomUserManager userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        //No es ideal dejar esto aca por lo cual se recomienda sacarlo una vez populada la base de datos
        app.InitializeDatabaseIdentity();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
            });
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseNodeModules(env.ContentRootPath);

        app.UseDistFolder(env.ContentRootPath);

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

        //esto esta aca solo para las pruebas jamas deberia existir
        app.InitializeDatabaseMock(userManager, roleManager);
    }
```

Edit:

1- When i say i cannot enter the webpage, i mean any endpoint from the idp server, not the part automatically handled by identity nor the part of my own mvc to handle the login and redirect, it just never reach a response from the server its waiting forever. On the server side, it doesnt matter where i put a breakpoint, no breakpoint is ever reached. But with a new sign in or the one that changes the password everything works just fine.

2- Finding number 2, i started a new project with only aspnet identity without identity server 4 and the cookie works flawlessly as is expected to work. i ll edit later but i ll be adding more things to the pipeline until i see what fails

Comment: `cannot ever enter the webpage again unless they delete manually the cookies`.Which the webpage you want to enter?Could you more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Rena I ll edit now with some findings. but i cannot enter any webpage on the idp, such as Login, ChangePass (this one im using to change the password of the current user). Doesnt matter if it has the [authorize] tag or not. It just get waiting for localhost... and never ends

Comment: Perhaps you have some exception that occures in IdentityServer? try to get to the logs of IdentityServer or enable app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); temporary to see if you can get a reason for the hang?